# All functions for every $.ajax.statusCode is called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to work with the Twitter RESTful API and also the $.ajax.statusCode, but it seems that all status code functions are called which confuses me. Using this skinned down example with an invalid URL:

```
$.ajax
(
    {
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/foobar",
        statusCode: {
            404: console.error("404"),
            410: console.error("410")
        },
        done: function(){console.info("done");},
        fail: function(){console.error("fail");}
    }
);
```

writes both the output for the 404 and 410 in the console. I'm using JQuery 1.10.2 but this also happens in 1.9.1. I checked the request history in Firefox and I can only see a single request which returns a http 404 response. Is there something here that I'm missing?

Comment: what about function() {console.error("404");}, ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`statusCode` is a map of status codes to functions:

```
statusCode : {
  404 : function() { console.log("404"); },
  410 : function() { console.log("410"); }
}
```

From [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> An object of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the
>   response has the corresponding code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsBVs/2/)

Comment: Are you getting both log lines even after correcting your `statusCode` object?

Comment: Sorry xbonez I screwed up by replacing my original comment. After I corrected the code I don't see the log entry for 404

Comment: That is just weird - it works fine on jsfiddle but if I copy-paste the exact same code to my local script file I don't get the console entry. If I modify the URL on jsfiddle to https://api.twitter.com/echo/foobar I also don't get the entry in the console

Comment: I don't think I can learn more from this. For some reason the console.log command does not act the way i would expect and since the JSFiddle works I will mark this as the answer. Thanks for helping me out xbonez!